# Hide excerpt in WP Job Manager resume list

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to delete the excerpt that appear on resume list in wp job manager. See the screenshot to understand better. Anyone knows how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you post link to this page, so that I can look into it .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove excerpts when you edit your page template file and remove the_excerpt(); function from it (be sure to move template to child theme first).

Or simpler method would be using CSS. Just write into your theme's custom CSS:

```
yourExcerptSelector{
    display: none;
}
```

(CSS will hide it but will not remove it)